# Route an error caused by middleware?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, middleware, rack-middleware

I have an app where I use the [apartment gem](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment), where I'm trying to route an error caused by the (apartment)middleware to a specific page and I have no clue how to solve this. I tried putting it into the controller, didn't help because it throws the error at the middleware layer. Putting it into routes didn't help either, because the apartment middleware gets executed just before the routes.